# Missing JPG file slowing down page load

Tags: wordpress

This is a WordPress site
There is a JPG file located in sub directory that is slowing down page load.

EXAMPLE 
mydomain.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/01/missing_file.jpg

File does not exist (missing-file.jpg)
Sub directories do not exist (2018/01/)
File load shows 404 in browser.
File / directory path shows up in performance test tools.

How do I get rid of all references to this missing directory and file?

Comment: You will need to identify on which page/post this is occurring, then edit that page. Without any information provided in your question about where this is happening the community cannot assist you.